# How to create dynamic table using the results

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

```
$.ajax({
 type: "post",
 url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>/controller_d/login/admin_search_user",
 cache: false,               
 data: $('#docContainer1').serialize(),
 dataType:"JSON",  //<----here
 success: function(json){   
      var str= "<table><tr>";
     $.each(json.query,function(i,v){
       alert(v.uID); //gives U0016
       alert(v.name); //gives saman
       str+="<td>"+v.uID+"</td>";
       str+="<td>"+v.name+"</td>";
    })
    str+="</tr></table">;
    $("body").append(str);
```

}

I want to create a dynamic table using json object values it must create a table but this is not working it will says v.ID not define

Comment: I just added the alert box to check but this is also not work

Comment: What is the server response?

Comment: are you sure all your objects inside json.query have the `uID` and `name` properties, if not then you need to check before using them

Comment: I am sure they are working

Answer (score 0):

```
row += "$('<td>').append("+dataString[i]+")";
```

or

```
var row = $('<tr>');
for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    row.append($('<td>').html(dataString[i]));
}

$('#results').append(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

create a table on the layout (on html code) then inside this create a `<tbody>` tag. assign an ID,  then on the success function of your jquery, use `$("#*tbody ID*").html` to assign the value on the tbody.

i've got this code on one of my projects. maybe you can use this as a reference (`tblApproved` is the id of the `tbody`):

```
function updateApprovedTable(){
        // retrieve Unit Record
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'php/requests.php',
            data:{mode:"getApproved"},
            success:function(data){
                $('#tblApproved').html(data);       

            }//success

        });//ajax       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please used this :

```
$.ajax({
 type: "post",
 url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>/controller_d/login/admin_search_user",
 cache: false,               
 data: $('#docContainer1').serialize(), 
 success: function(data){
    $("body").append(data);
});
```

Also write your code for table create into this url "/controller_d/login/admin_search_user"

**PHP Code**

```
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><td>content</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>content</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>content</td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
```